# Problems with splash screen, segue and timers

Tags: objective-c, nstimer, segue, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen with timer and segue, that wil be performed after 2 seconds.It is a piece of code frome my SplashScreenClass.m. What is wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(performSegue)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)performSegue{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splash" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, it is recommended that splash screens not be used.  Your app could get rejected for this reason.

Comment: Thanks, but how can it be realised? In spite of Human Interface Guidelines? Just theoretically?

Comment: I have used splash screens in few apps and each of them passed the Apple review. It's important that they do not last too long.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution to use timer for solving this problem. I recommend performing selector after delay instead. It's quite easier to use. Just put this line in your viewDidLoad method.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(performSegue) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: It does not work. Xcode shows the same problem "Thread 1:signal SIGABR"

Comment: There should not be a problem with this line. Maybe you have some troubles with your storyboard and seque.

Comment: What the problem can it be?